A submanifold is locally a slice of a coordinate system. A proof from O'Neill, "Semi-Riemannian Geometry"
Let $ M $ be a manifold. Let $ P $ be a submanifold of $ M $. In this post, this is supposed to mean that $ P $ is a subset of $ M $ that endowed with the subspace topology is itself a manifold for which the canonical injection $ P\hookrightarrow M $ is a smooth immersion.
I want to show that for each $ p\in P $ there is a coordinate system $ \xi = (x^1,\dots,x^n)\colon \mathcal U\to \mathbb R $ of $ M $ near $ p $ such that $ P\cap \mathcal U $ is the $ \xi $-coordinate slice
$$
\mathcal U\cap M = \Bigl\{q\in M : x^{i_1}(q) = \dots = x^{i_m}(q) = 0\Bigr\}
$$
for some $ i_1,\dots,i_m\in \{1,\dots,n\} $, $ m = \dim P $.
I'm reading the proof given in O'Neill, Semi-Riemannian Geometry: With Applications to Relativity, Proposition 28. I got stuck at some point because I couldn't decipher what O'Neill was trying to say.
The proof goes like this. Take $ p\in M $ and suppose $ (x^1,\dots,x^n) $ is a coordinate system of $ M $ near $ p $ and $ (y^1,\dots,y_m) $ is a coordinate system of $ P $ near $ p $. One can show that there are some variables among the $ x^\mu $ that together make up a coordinate system of $ S $ near $ p $. Up to reordering, they are $ x^1\rvert_P,\dots,x^m\rvert_P $. At this point the author claims

If $ f^k $ is the coordinate expression for $ x^k\rvert_P $ relative to these coordinates, then
$$
x^k = f^k(x^1,\dots,x^m)\,\text{.}
$$
It follows that the functions
$$
z^k = x^k - f^k(x^1,\dots,x^m)
$$
are well defined on some neighborhood of $ p $ in $ M $.

What is all that supposed to mean? It's totally unclear to me how $ f^k $ is defined.

If I'm not mistaken, you are confused about that the definition of $f^k$ as "the coordinate expression for $x^k|_P$ relative to these coordinates". I'll try to define those explicitly.
The coordinates are functions, of the type: $$x^k:M \to \mathbb{R}.$$
We recall that $(x^1,\dots, x^m)$ is a coordinate system around
$$
\begin{align}
p&\in U\subset P\subset M\qquad \text{Where:}\\
&\quad U\ \text{  is an open subset of }\ P
\end{align}
$$
Coordinates systems allow us to identify, via a diffeomorphism, $\mathbb{R}^m \simeq U$. We can thus define a function
$$\begin{align} f:\mathbb{R}^m &\to \mathbb{R} ,\quad s.t.\\
&f\circ (x^1,\dots,x^m)=x^k|_U
\end{align}
$$
This is the expression of $x^k$ in local coordinates, relative to the coordinate system $(x^1,\dots,x^m)$.
Note that the composition $f\circ (x^1,\dots,x^m)$ is a function of the type $M\to \mathbb{R}$, and that the choice of $f$ is dependent on the coordinates $(x^1,\dots,x^m)$ we've fixed.
Further note that we could pull off this stunt with any function $g:M\to \mathbb{R}$, not just with $x^k$.
Writing functions in local coordinates is useful when one wants to calculate stuff for maps between manifolds; You identify them with euclidean functions, do the calculations in $\mathbb{R}$, and push the results back to the manifold using the coordinates.
